# Less CSS - class declaration in html?

Tags: css, less

I get where less could be used, but doing this (which doesn't work):

```
<div class="fixed-width(150px)" ></div>

.fixed-width(@customWidth) {
   width: @customWidth;
}
```

...seems like it makes more sense than the offered example of:

```
<div class="fixed-width" ></div>

.fixed-width {
   .another-step(150px);
}

.another-step(@customWidth) {
   width: @customWidth;
}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to you.  It doesn't to me.  Less CSS is about making stylesheets easier to maintain.  It's not about getting itself involved with your HTML.

Comment: This would make *everything* easier to maintain :)

Comment: @Frank: This would make everything *harder* to maintain, IMO. Classes should denote what *type* of object the element is, not what look it has.

Comment: Whatever solution that does this would have to either pre-parse your HTML (not easily done when you involve dynamically generated HTML from server-side languages) and generate a stylesheet accordingly or parse it at run-time and generate/cache & append a stylesheet.  For simple examples such as the one you provided, you may as well just use `style="width: 150px"`.  Anyway, it's out of the scope of Less CSS.

Comment: I hate that style tag!  Harder to maintain, You?  Maybe that's relative.  I just think it makes sense to be able to declare classes with variables, like almost every other language :)  Too bad, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. LESS compiles the CSS file only, not the inline CSS as well. You'd have to write an improved parser to generate the code you're already using.

Comment: There is no inline CSS involved either, making the given HTML completely irrelevant to LESS.